# ActivityGroup Example

Tags: android, activitygroup

Can anybody please give me an example of ActivityGroup. I have heard that by making use of ActivityGroup we can change the nested activities maintaining the TabHost as it is.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
david brown

Answer (score 10, accepted):

david here is a an example I found useful:

http://ericharlow.blogspot.com/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html

Comment: FYI, the first link is dead. This answer would be much better if you included actual code directly in it.

Comment: ActivityGroup is now deprecated. use Fragment.

Comment: @dipu How to use fragment any link or tutorial please. Thanks