# Android: ActivityGroup tutorial with example

Tags: android, activitygroup

Can u please suggest a good tutorial (with example) for ActivityGroup. I am completely new about this topic.

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [ActivityGroup Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568468/activitygroup-example)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you trying to extend ActivityGroup in your project with specific requirements? [Here is a tutorial](http://web.archive.org/web/20100816175634/http://blog.henriklarsentoft.com/2010/07/android-tabactivity-nested-activities/) with a TabActivity and ActivityGroup.

Comment: Here is another [example](http://united-coders.com/nico-heid/use-android-activitygroup-within-tabhost-to-show-different-activity)

Comment: the link of the tutorial is broken! the example is fine

Comment: hey do any of you know if this is an issue for new Android OS?  I saw that ActivityGroups are now deprecated.

Comment: @MikeIsrael It's depreciated in favour of Fragment and FragmentManager.

Comment: @AndrewWeir does that mean utilizing them instead of fragments will cause issues?  I know sometimes deprecated methods will cause programs to crash.

Comment: @Mikelsrael It shouldn't cause them to crash, no. I'm currently building an app using ActivityGroups and debugging it on ICS. It just means as time goes on, the code will become less supported and for new versions of Android, you may see more unpredictable behaviour.