# Multiple Activity under same tab Space

Tags: android, tabview

I am building an app that has a tab view and my tabview has two tabs.
1. Map View
2. List View

```
 TabSpec mapTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid1");
 TabSpec listTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid1");
 mapTabSpec.setIndicator("ListView", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.logo))
 .setContent(new Intent(this,ListViewEvents.class));
 listTabSpec.setIndicator("Map View", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.logo))
 .setContent(new Intent(this,MapViewEvents.class));
  tabHost.addTab(mapTabSpec);
  tabHost.addTab(listTabSpec);
```

In list View on click a list item i want to load another activity(page) which has to show under same tab ie. under the list view tab.

How i accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for Activity group here.Using Activity Groups you can move on to other activities with the tab being displayed.  These links will get you started,

[ActivityGroup Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4568468/603744)

http://blog.henriklarsentoft.com/2010/07/android-tabactivity-nested-activities/