# Is it possible to show tab host on overall application in android

Tags: android, android-tabhost

Can I implement a tab host which will remain in overall application and works through out the application .

and

Also can i implement the tab host on the top and on the bottom of the same activity.

Any tutorial any help please....

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible if you use Activity Group. But still it is deprecated and hence you cannot use it for newer versions of android. But still, you can go through what it is and try to implement it.

[ActivityGroup Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4568468/603744)

http://blog.henriklarsentoft.com/2010/07/android-tabactivity-nested-activities/

http://gamma-point.com/content/android-how-have-multiple-activities-under-single-tab-tabactivity

So now since Activity Groups are deprecated what is the alternate strategy we can make use of? Here is the solution for this problem.

```
                      Go for fragments or Views.
```

I have pasted the comment which I recieved from [Commonsware](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) regarding the ActivityGroup.

**You never needed ActivityGroup to use tabs. You can put views in tabs, for example ([github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Fancy/Tab](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Fancy/Tab)). Going forward, tabs are in the action bar on Honeycomb, typically using fragments. You can achieve the same functionality on previous versions of Android using ActionBarSherlock.**