# Tabs disappears in TabActivity after it goes to other Activities

Tags: android, tabs

In my app I have four tabs in the bottom of my main screen. When the user click in one of the tabs in the bottom it open an Activity and the user needs to fill up a form, after the form is done it returns to one of the TabActivities.

Everything works well, except when the form is save its supposed to go to the Activity an show the four tabs in the bottom. The problem is that the tabs in the bottom disappear.

I thought the if Im calling the TabActivity it will always show the tabs that were assign in the XML layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay you have to go for ActivityGroups. But in later version of android Activity Group is deprecated and hence you have to go for fragments or views. Here are few links which will get you started.

[ActivityGroup Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4568468/603744)

http://blog.henriklarsentoft.com/2010/07/android-tabactivity-nested-activities/

http://united-coders.com/nico-heid/use-android-activitygroup-within-tabhost-to-show-different-activity